# React app on App Engine not finding static files with custom domain

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

I deployed my app to App Engine and it works with the default subdomain that is auto generated. However, after going through the steps in the mapping a custom domain section of the docs I can't see it at the custom domain.

here's my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10

service: platform

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: try with removing leading / after css, like `upload: build/static/css(.*)` instead of `upload: build/static/css/(.*)`, also with js

Comment: @PraveenSoni doesn't work

Comment: try `url: /static
    static_dir: build/static`